# Is it possible to get source code from the official web site and change it and resell it for ErpNext?

Tags: gnu, erp, erpnext

I want To Ask About The licence for ErpNext ERP GNU GPL3 , is it possible to get source code and change it and resell it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing, not about developing. Consider reasking it on http://opensource.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: thank,s i will care about that next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are talking about here is illeagal under theft of intellectual property, if the source code is not listed as "public domain" code odds are it belongs to someone